# Applying non-linear dimensionality reduction on binary data

Tags: categorical-data, pca, dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional, manifold-learning

Would be beneficial to apply nonlinear dimensionality reduction on a binary dataset (around 200 binary features) ? what is difference from applying  MCA (multiple correspondence analysis).

Comment: Please accept answers to your many questions across the various StackExchange sites. You are starting to look very selfish, and I'm sure you wouldn't want that